# How get the Value of DropDown in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a drop down list in my MVC view as :

```
 <select id="organization" class="create-user-select-half"></select>
```

I try to get the value of dropdown in Type Script like this:

```
 var e = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("organization")).value;
```

but it return empty, this is how I get the textbox value and it is working. Also I tired this code but options and selectedIndex are undefined.

```
 var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
 var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: Where is the value? Try this `<select id="organization" class="create-user-select-half"><option value="1">One</option></select>`

Answer (score 10):

You need to use the HTMLSelectElement instead, but this can be tricky

```
    var e = (document.getElementById("organization")) as HTMLSelectElement;
    var sel = e.selectedIndex;
    var opt = e.options[sel];
    var CurValue = (<HTMLSelectElement>opt).value;
    var CurText = (<HTMLSelectElement>opt).text;
```

You will need to define the value or text though if you want anything back

```
    '<select id="organization" value="ThisIsMyValue">This is my text</select>
```

Output 
**CurValue** = "ThisIsMyValue" 
**CurText** = "This is my text"

Comment: this worked for me except that I had to cast to HTMLOptionElement
var selVal = (<HTMLOptionElement>opt).value;
var selText = (<HTMLOptionElement>opt).text;

Answer (score 7):

You only need this line of code:

```
let value = (<HTMLSelectElement>document.getElementById('organization')).value;
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
const target = e.target as HTMLSelectElement
console.log("%s is selected", (target[clickedIndex] as HTMLOptionElement).value)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Angular 9 and the following worked for me:

**(document.getElementById("inputCategory") as HTMLSelectElement).value**

My suggestion is for you to refactor your statement to:

**var e = (document.getElementById("organization") as HTMLSelectElement).value**

*Happy coding!*

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In HTML:

```
<select #organization (change)="selectOrganization(organization.value)" class="create-user-select-half">
    <option *ngFor="let o of organizationList"
        [value]="organization.id" 
        [selected]="organizationFromDB == o.organization_name">
        {{ o.organization_name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

In TS:

```
selectOrganization(id) {
    console.log('id', id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $any typecast function

> $any($event.target).value

Which will stop the type checking in the template
In below code updatePageSize takes a number as argument:

```
<select (change) = "updatePageSize($any($event.target).value)">
   <option selected = "true">5</option>                                        
   <option>10</option>                                        
   <option>20</option>
   <option>50</option>
</select>
```

Credits:https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget-error-in-angular/